# Open new window with url built by javascript

Tags: javascript, href

What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="#"onclick="javascript:window.open(getBaseUrl() + '/handler/licensing/api/GetClients')">REST URL</a>
```

Right now all this is doing is moving me to the top of the page appending # to the url. I want it to open a new window with the resulting url. How can I debug this?

Comment: You have an obvious syntax error that a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) would pick up, you have a pointless [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) at the start of your function, you're using the horrible `onclick` attribute, you haven't shared `getBaseUrl` with us, and you haven't told us which browsers you've tested in or what their error consoles say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does getBaseUrl() exist? Also you could put a space in there after the href="#" or remove the javascript: from the onclick attribute as onclick is already javascript.

Comment: It exists, it populates off of fields earlier on the page I filled out. The reason it wasn't working is because before I clicked the link after I filled out the fields I would click the activex alert saying allow blocked content. That for some reason resets all the fields to null making the url invalid.

So as long as I populate the fields after I allow the block content it worked great. Thank you both for the quick response, figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Remove javascript: from onclick defination. OnClick is already javascript context.

Make that:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open(getBaseUrl() + '/handler/licensing/api/GetClients')">REST URL</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(getBaseUrl() + '/handler/licensing/api/GetClients')">REST URL</a>
```

Comment: Having a label at the start of that function is useless, but it won't prevent the script from working.